# Fancybox Error with jQuery

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Simple Fancybox implementation:

```
<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $path ?>/scripts/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.6" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $path ?>/scripts/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.6"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".bte-banner").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 400,
        maxHeight   : 500,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : 400,
        height      : 500,
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'fade',
        closeEffect : 'fade',
        type        : 'iframe'
    });
});
</script>
```

...

```
<a class="bte-banner" href="pages/products/"><img src="images/banners/imagename.png"></a>
```

I keep getting this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined

Anyone run into this or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

mootools conflict from joomla plugin. jQuery.noConflict solved it.
http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries